# finding the frequency of each row (3)

Tags: matlab

Per my previous question couple days ago, now, I have several mx3 matrices with rows from (0,1,num), (-1,0,num), (0,1,num), (0,-1,num), (1,1,num), (-1,1,num), (1,-1,num),(-1,-1,num), where num is an integer which can take any values between 0 to 3. 
I would like to create a new matrix, with 8 rows, and 6 columns, where the the first two columns represent each of the above coordinates, and each of the remaining columns indicate the frequency 
of each of the above coordinates at each num values. i.e. columns 3 of each row indicates the number of times we see the coordinate corresponding to that row with and num=0. columns 4 of each row indicates the number of times we see the coordinate corresponding to that row with and num=1.
columns 5 of each row indicates the number of times we see the coordinate corresponding to that row with and num=2, and columns 6 of each row indicates the number of times we see the coordinate corresponding to that row with and num=3.

For instance, if  A=[0     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     0
     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     1    -1     0
     1     1     0
     1     1     3
     1     1     2
     1     1     3
     1     1     3]

I would like to see something like:
    -1    -1   0 0 0 0
    -1     0   0 0 0 0
    -1     1   0 0 0 0
     0    -1   0 0 0 0
     0     1   0 1 0 0
     1    -1   1 0 0 0
     1     0   1 0 0 0
     1     1   7 1 1 3 
Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
counts = zeros(9, 6); % Initialize output matrix

k = 1;
for ii = -1:1
    for jj = -1:1
        ijCoords = (A(:,1) == ii) & (A(:,2) == jj); % Find rows containing coordinate (ii,jj)
        ijCount = histc(A(ijCoords,3), 0:3); % Count how many 0,1,2,3 in these rows
        counts(k,:) = [ii, jj, ijCount(:)']; % Add the counts to the next row of the output matrix
        k = k + 1;
    end
end

counts(5, :) = []; % Remove coordinate (0,0) because you don't want it.
```